# Export entire regex group to text file

Tags: python, regex, export, text-files, regex-group

When I print the group "**print(a)**" the entire group is shown. When I save it to a text file **"open("sirs1.txt", "w").write(a)"** only the last row is saved to the file.

```
import re

def main():
f = open('sirs.txt')
for lines in f:
    match = re.search('(AA|BB|CC|DD)......', lines)
    if match:
        a = match.group()
        print(a)
        open("sirs1.txt", "w").write(a)
```

How do I save the entire group to the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nosklo is correct the main problem is that you are overwriting the whole file each time you write to it. mehmattski is also correct in that you will also need to explicitly add \n to each write in order to make the output file readable.

Try this:

```
enter code here

import re

def main():
  f = open('sirs.txt') 
  outputfile = open('sirs1.txt','w')

  for lines in f:
    match = re.search('(AA|BB|CC|DD)......', lines)
    if match:
      a = match.group()
      print(a)
      outputfile.write(a+"\n")

  f.close()
  outputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

the `open` command creates a new file, so you're creating a new file every time.

Try to create the file outside the for-loop

```
import re
def main():
    with open('sirs.txt') as f:
        with open("sirs1.txt", "w") as fw:
            for lines in f:
                match = re.search('(AA|BB|CC|DD)......', lines)
                if match:
                    a = match.group()
                    print(a)
                    fw.write(a)
```

Comment: I hate nested `with` statements, they make indentation explode. Luckily, you can flatten them in more recent Python versions: `with open('sirs.txt') as f, open("sirs1.txt", "w") as fw`.

Comment: Thanks, but the method above created a long string with no spaces in it. Is there a way to save it to the file as a list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a newline character after each string to get them to print on separate lines:

```
import re

def main():
   f = open('sirs.txt')
   outputfile = open('sirs1.txt','w')
   for lines in f:
      match = re.search('(AA|BB|CC|DD)......', lines)
      if match:
          a = match.group()
          print(a)
          outputfile.write(a+'/n')
   f.close()
   outputfile.close()
```